# Lines not plotting on graph using Python/Basemap

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pandas, matplotlib-basemap

Sorry if this question is simple I'm a newb to using Python and Basemap. Anyway I'm trying to plot the path of 20 hurricanes on a map (graph). The map itself and the legend show up perfectly but the paths of the hurricanes do not. Also I'm not getting any traceback messages but I think I have an idea of where my problem may be. Could someone please tell me where I went wrong.

Here's a sample of the csv file:

```
Year, Name, Type, Latitude, Longitude
1957,AUDREY,HU, 21.6, 93.3
1957,AUDREY,HU,22.0,  93.4
1957,AUDREY,HU,22.6,  93.5
1969,AUDREY,HU,28.2,99.6
1957,AUDREY,HU,26.5,93.8
1957,AUDREY,HU,27.9,93.8
1957,AUDREY,HU,29.3,95
1957,AUDREY,HU,27.9,93.8
1957,AUDREY,HU,29.3,93.8
1957,AUDREY,HU,30.7,93.5
1969,CAMILLE,HU, 21.6,99.3
1969,CAMILLE,HU,22.0,98.4
1969,CAMILLE,HU,22.6,90.5
1969,CAMILLE,HU,23.2,93.6
```

Here's the code I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv, os, scipy
import pandas
from PIL import *


data = np.loadtxt('louisianastormb.csv',dtype=np.str,delimiter=',',skiprows=1)
'''print data'''
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))

ax = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8])

m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-100.,llcrnrlat=0.,urcrnrlon=-20.,urcrnrlat=57.,
            projection='lcc',lat_1=20.,lat_2=40.,lon_0=-60.,
            resolution ='l',area_thresh=1000.)

m.bluemarble()
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.5)
m.drawcountries(linewidth=0.5)
m.drawstates(linewidth=0.5)

# Creates parallels and meridians
m.drawparallels(np.arange(10.,35.,5.),labels=[1,0,0,1])
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-120.,-80.,5.),labels=[1,0,0,1])
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
color_dict = {'AUDREY': 'red', 'ETHEL': 'white', 'BETSY': 'yellow','CAMILLE': 'blue', 'CARMEN': 'green','BABE': 'purple', }


colnames = ['Year','Name','Type','Latitude','Longitude']
data = pandas.read_csv('louisianastormb.csv', names=colnames)
names = list(data.Name)
lat = list(data.Latitude)
long = list(data.Longitude)
colorName = list(data.Name)
#print lat
#print long
lat.pop(0)
long.pop(0)
colorName.pop(0)
latitude= map(float, lat)
longitude = map(float, long)
x, y = m(latitude,longitude)
#Plots points on map
for colorName in color_dict.keys():
    plt.plot(x,y,linestyle ='-',label=colorName,color=color_dict[colorName], linewidth=5 )
    lg = plt.legend()
    lg.get_frame().set_facecolor('grey')
plt.show()
```

Comment: is it possible for you to upload the csv data file as well, or just a stripped version for a minimal working example?

Comment: @nye17 Sure I just added a sample of the csv file. I'm not able to upload the entire file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

two (okay I lied, should be there) problems with your code

i, your input longitude should be negative to be within the boundary you defined for your basemap, so add this after before converting to x and y

```
longitude = [-i for i in longitude]
```

ii, your coordinate conversion line is wrong, you should swap lon and lat in the argument list

```
x, y = m(longitude, latitude)
```

instead of

```
x, y = m(latitude,longitude)
```

EDIT:

okay, the second question that OP posted in the comments, please check the complete code below and please pay attention to the changes I've made compared to yours

```
# Last-modified: 21 Oct 2013 05:35:16 PM

import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv, os, scipy
import pandas
from PIL import *


data = np.loadtxt('louisianastormb.csv',dtype=np.str,delimiter=',',skiprows=1)
'''print data'''
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))

ax = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8])

m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-100.,llcrnrlat=0.,urcrnrlon=-20.,urcrnrlat=57.,
            projection='lcc',lat_1=20.,lat_2=40.,lon_0=-60.,
            resolution ='l',area_thresh=1000.)

m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.5)
m.drawcountries(linewidth=0.5)
m.drawstates(linewidth=0.5)
# m.bluemarble(ax=ax)

# Creates parallels and meridians
m.drawparallels(np.arange(10.,35.,5.),labels=[1,0,0,1])
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-120.,-80.,5.),labels=[1,0,0,1])
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
color_dict = {'AUDREY': 'red', 'ETHEL': 'white', 'BETSY': 'yellow','CAMILLE': 'blue', 'CARMEN': 'green','BABE': 'purple', }

colnames = ['Year','Name','Type','Latitude','Longitude']
data = pandas.read_csv('louisianastormb.csv', names=colnames)
names = list(data.Name)
lat = list(data.Latitude)
long = list(data.Longitude)
colorNames = list(data.Name)
#print lat
#print long
lat.pop(0)
long.pop(0)
colorNames.pop(0)
latitude= map(float, lat)
longitude = map(float, long)
# added by nye17
longitude = [-i for i in longitude]
# x, y = m(latitude,longitude)
x, y = m(longitude,latitude)
# convert to numpy arrays
x = np.atleast_1d(x)
y = np.atleast_1d(y)
colorNames = np.atleast_1d(colorNames)
#Plots points on map
for colorName in color_dict.keys():
    plt.plot(x[colorName == colorNames],y[colorName == colorNames],linestyle ='-',label=colorName,color=color_dict[colorName], linewidth=5 )
    lg = plt.legend()
    lg.get_frame().set_facecolor('grey')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!! However now all the the lines are being plotted in the same color. How can I fix this so that the paths of the hurricanes are the matches the colors in my color dictionary. For example Hurricane Audrey's path would be red, Ethel's path would be blue, etc.

Comment: @mikez1 You should ask one question per thread.  If this answer solved you asked in your original post, then you should accept it (big gray checkbox)  If you have more or new questions you should create a new question thread.

Comment: @tcaswell Ok sorry about that.

Comment: @mikez1 listen to tcaswell, but for this time alone, please check my edited answer.

Comment: @mikez1 You seem new here, so don't worry about it too much.  The logic of one question per-thread is to make the site as useful as possible to future readers.  It also helps to not drive answers crazy, it is very frustrating when the goal posts keep moving.

Comment: @nye17 Thanks for all of your help. I do have one more question but I'll create another question thread for it.

Comment: @mikez1 you don't need to, just check my code above --- I plotted the path of each hurricane using different colors defined by your dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I think your difficulty is not so much in Basemap as in the plotting.  Instead of plotting the entire x/y data set you need to find the x/y points corresponding on hurricane Z.  Then plot only those points in a certain color c.  Then find the points corresponding to the next hurricane etc...

The below, while not using the Basemap data structure should provide a starting point for plotting subsets of points based on some selector vector.

```
#given a list of x,y coordinates with a  label we'll plot each line individually

#first construct some points to plot
x1 = [1,1.1,1.2,1.3, 2.0,2.2,2.3, 4,3.9,3.8,3.7]
y1 = [5,5.1,5.2,5.3, 6.0,6.2,6.3, 2,2.1,2.2,2.3]
pointNames = []
#generate some labels
pointNames.extend(['a']*4)
pointNames.extend(['b']*3)
pointNames.extend(['c']*4)

#make things easy by casting to numpy arrays to allow for easier indexing
x1 = numpy.array(x1)
y1 = numpy.array(y1)
pointNames = numpy.array(pointNames)

for elem in ['a','b','c']:
  selector = pointNames==elem
  subsetX = x1[selector]
  subsetY = y1[selector]
  #now plot subsetX vs subsetY in color Z
  plot(subsetX,subsetY,'*-')

show()
```

Comment: Ok thanks for your response. I think I understand what you are saying, but I have a file with 20 hurricanes, the type and the coordinates, etc. Is there a simple way to group all coordinates based on the name of the hurricane and plot them?

Comment: Sure in that case you can use set function to get the unique string names (hurricanes).   s1 = set(['a','b','c','c'])  gives s1:('a','b','c') as as tuple. You can loop through each one: for elem in s1.  In your case the pointNames is the list/array of strings - names.  So you would do s1 = set(names) to get the unique hurricane names then loop on that.

Comment: Ok in my code I already have a color dictionary (color_dict) with the name of the hurricane. Based on my code above would this be correct: (I used n1 because names is already used in my code)                                                         `for n1, track in data.groupby('Name'):
    latitude = track.Lat.values
    longitude = track.Lon.values
    #Convert latitude and longitude to coordinates X and Y
    x, y = m(longitude, latitude)
    #Plot the points on the map
    pl.plot(x,y,'-', label=n1, color=colors_dict[n1])`